# Why elastic search query with parenthesis and without parenthesis give different output?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have 2 below elastic search query

This give 5 result

```
POST twitter/object/_search
{

 "_source": false,
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "Apple AND Orange OR Banana",
     "default_field": "content"
    }
  }
}
```

This give 12 result

```
POST twitter/object/_search
{

 "_source": false,
 "query": {
   "query_string": {
     "query": "(Apple AND Orange) OR Banana",
     "default_field": "content"
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me out why it's happening. How the query is interpret because logically both queries should give same output?

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators

> The familiar boolean operators AND, OR and NOT are supported but
>   beware that they do not honor the usual precedence rules, so
>   parentheses should be used whenever multiple operators are used
>   together.

Comment: We have gone through both query but we can't find the any solution  on why hit counts are different for mention two queries.

Comment: Because of the parentheses.

Comment: We also have the same question. yes, we know its because of parenthesis but the main question is how it interprets the first query without parenthesis?

Comment: Elastic don't specify how it is interpreted so it is at best undefined or non-deterministic. The solution is to use parentheses, as they advise.